# System tags box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

> Add these effects to the code jquery.

As add **tag** automatically by separating them with a comma.

> Without pressing enter.

How to disable or delete the warning to delete a tag.

Code of the system:

```js
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  // ::: TAGS BOX

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

```css
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  background:#789;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags > span:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags > span:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:2px 5px;
 margin-left:3px;
 font-size:11px;
}
#tags > input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
  <span>php</span>
  <span>c++</span>
  <span>jquery</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>
```

> If possible provide an example of as depend on a database to select **tags** according to records in the database.

Comment: change **if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) $(this).remove();** and remove the if condition like so: **$(this).remove();**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){ // DOM ready

  // ::: TAGS BOX

  $("#tags input").on({
    focusout : function() {
      var txt = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) $("<span/>", {text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
      this.value = "";
    },
    keyup : function(ev) {
      // if: comma|enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });
  $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
  });

});
```

```css
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags > span{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  background:#789;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags > span:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags > span:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"×";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:2px 5px;
 margin-left:3px;
 font-size:11px;
}
#tags > input{
  background:#eee;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tags">
  <span>php</span>
  <span>c++</span>
  <span>jquery</span>
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Add a tag" />
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect friend. Now as add tag automatically by separating by comma, without pressing enter. Any idea?

Comment: what exactly is not working for you about the comma? if you type `bla,` then bla is automatically added as a tag without the need to press enter